# DjangoCMS NavigationNode - custom node

Tags: python, django, django-cms

The default NavigationNode in [DjangoCMS](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/menus.html?highlight=navigationnode) has nodes as:

- children
- title
- get_menu_title
- get_attribute
- etc.

In the same context, I want to add my custom node, called: **category**_**name** which would return a string 'something' (just for testing purposes).

Following the [official documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/index.html), nothing that would help me solve my issue, was found. When looking up for the declaration of default NavigationNode, the following code appears:

> from menus.base import NavigationNode

**base.py** file:

```
class NavigationNode(object):

    def __init__(self, title, url, id, parent_id=None, parent_namespace=None,
                 attr=None, visible=True):
        self.children = []  # do not touch
        self.parent = None  # do not touch, code depends on this
        self.namespace = None  # TODO: Assert why we need this and above
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
        self.id = id
        self.parent_id = parent_id
        self.parent_namespace = parent_namespace
        self.visible = visible
        self.attr = attr or {} # To avoid declaring a dict in defaults...

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Navigation Node: %s>" % smart_str(self.title)

    def get_menu_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.url

    def get_attribute(self, name):
        return self.attr.get(name, None)

    def get_descendants(self):
        return sum(([node] + node.get_descendants() for node in self.children), [])

    def get_ancestors(self):
        if getattr(self, 'parent', None):
            return [self.parent] + self.parent.get_ancestors()
        else:
            return []
```

If I add my custom node called category_name here, it will work. But it is not a smart solution to modify base files.

**So my question is:**

> How to add my custom node outside the base.py ? i.E. if I want to add
>   it in my apps models.py file.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The answer is: Yes! It is possible.

As it states in the documentation, you can use **modify()** method.

But it did not work for me, because I got confused with  `node.attr["changed_by"]` . In templates, I wanted to use something like this: `{{ child.category_name }}` but as it is obvious, I was modifying it wrong.

The correct way is this:

```
from menus.base import Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool

from cms.models import Page

class MyMode(Modifier):
    """

    """
    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        # if the menu is not yet cut, don't do anything
        if post_cut:
            return nodes
        # otherwise loop over the nodes
        for node in nodes:
            # does this node represent a Page?
            if node.attr["is_page"]:
                # if so, put its changed_by attribute on the node
                node.category_name = "Some category name here"
        return nodes

menu_pool.register_modifier(MyMode)
```

Now, in menu.html, you can use child.category_name and it will output the string  "Some category name here"

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}
<li>
    {% if child.children %}
    <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ child.get_menu_title }} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="menu-vertical">
        {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <a class1="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}" href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">
            {% if child.category_name %}
                <b>{{ child.category }}</b>
            {% endif %}
            {{ child.get_menu_title }}
        </a>
    {% endif %}
</li>
{% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, after hours and hours of attempts, I solved this.